# Code doesn't work with ajax pager

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I have this code that turns youtube links into embeds, however I made ajax pager for my forum threads and now when I go to another page then the links are not turned into embeds anymore (it's drupal and views pager). What to do about it?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "a:contains('youtu')" ).each(function() {
        var yt_url = this.href,
            yt_id = yt_url.split('?v=')[1],
            yt_title = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="youtube-box" style="background-image:url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + yt_id + '/0.jpg);"><span class="youtube-title">' + yt_title + '</span><span class="youtube-bar"><span class="yt-bar-left"></span><span class="yt-bar-right"></span></span><span class="youtube-play">Start</span></div>');
        $('div.youtube-box').click(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith('<iframe class="youtube-frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + yt_id + '" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your javascript runs when the page is loaded, but not after an ajax call.
Your should be using [drupal behaviors](http://www.amazeelabs.com/en/blog/drupal-behaviors-quick-how). Functions in the drupal behaviors object are run when the page has loaded, and after ajax calls are complete.
Do it like this:

```
(function($) {
      Drupal.behaviors.mybehavior = {
        attach:function(context, settings){

          $( "a:contains('youtu')", context ).each(function() {
              var yt_url = this.href,
                  yt_id = yt_url.split('?v=')[1],
                  yt_title = $(this).text();
              var newstuff = $('<div class="youtube-box" style="background-image:url(http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + yt_id + '/0.jpg);"><span class="youtube-title">' + yt_title + '</span><span class="youtube-bar"><span class="yt-bar-left"></span><span class="yt-bar-right"></span></span><span class="youtube-play">Start</span></div>');
              newstuff.click(function() {
                  $(this).replaceWith('<iframe class="youtube-frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + yt_id + '" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
              });
              $(this).replaceWith(newstuff);
          });
        }
      };
})(jQuery);
```

I also changed the code a little to store the new content in a variable so as to not have to use jquery to select it again.
This is all untested though.